# How do I manage virtual network settings in VMWare Player?

Tags: vmware-player

In former times, there was a `vmnetcfg.exe` present with the VMWare Player distribution.

Using `vmnetcfg.exe`, one was able to configure the VMWare network settings like setting up a port forwarding for NAT and so on.

Unfortunately, `vmnetcfg.exe` is no longer present in newer installations of VMWare player.

How do I manage the network settings with a newer player installation?

Comment: Some net options can be set by editing the config files, like: `C:\ProgramData\VMware\vmnetnat.conf ` see: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-C2EC7B92-A499-4B47-95B6-0BFDDA28AC34.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There are at least two possibilities to get hands on the VMWare Network Settings again.

- extract `vmnetcfg.exe` from a VMWare Workstation setup file
- execute vmnetcfg using `vmnetui.dll`

#### How to extract `vmnetcfg.exe` from a VMWare Workstation setup file?

If you still have the setup file used for installing the player, you could extract the `vmnetcfg.exe` from this setup file:

- download a VMWare Workstation setup matching your VMWare Player version from http://www.vmware.com/go/downloadworkstation
- open a command prompt where your setup file is (e.g. `C:/temp/download`)
- unpack the setup file using
  `VMware-workstation-full-VERSION.exe  /e target_dir`
  This will create `target_dir` and unpack the contents of the installer there
- locate `core.cab` in the fresh `target_dir` folder
- open `core.cab` with an archiver capable of reading `.cab` files
- copy `vmnetcfg.exe` from the archive to the install directory of your VMWare Player
- execute `vmnetcfg.exe`

However, this method has some drawbacks:

- need to download the workstation installer first
- need to download a workstation setup matching your player version
- manual interaction

To have an easier way, read on.

#### How to execute `vmnetcfg` using `vmnetui.dll`?

While the player installation doesn't contain `vmnetcfg.exe` anymore, there's a file called `vmnetui.dll` present in the installation folder of your VMWare Player. To bring up the UI of the network config, do this:

- open a command promt **as administrator**
- navigate to your install folder of VMWare Player
- execute `rundll32 vmnetui.dll,VMNetUI_ShowStandalone`

This will bring up the VMWare network settings dialog.

Comment: the last option doesn't seem to work anymore on VMWare Player 12

Comment: Neither does it work on v7.

Comment: in my "vmware player 12.1.1", that dll doesn't even exist. and there's no such command line parameter in the installer. there is an "x" switch which is supposed to extract everything to %temp% , but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Any idea how to get network settings if the host system is linux?

Comment: @vextorspace: never used VMWare on Linux, sorry.

Comment: Just found this: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-C2EC7B92-A499-4B47-95B6-0BFDDA28AC34.html

Comment: Extracting a few more files (a DLL is needed, don't remember which) will make it work even with version 7.x. Also if you keep those files around (in a separate folder), they work even with newer versions, like 12.x. They just edit _vmnetnat.conf_ (see comment on the question) and restart the VM NAT service.

Comment: it is still working with workstation v16 but files are located in `Workstation.cab`. If you put in a random folder it will complain that the following dll are missing: `vmwarebase.dll`, `vmwarecui.dll`, `sigc_2.0.dll` and `vmapputil.dll`. I put  `vmnetcfg.exe` in the folder of the VM Player and it works :)